# Match user input from whole csv file R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

Sorry for this question i m newbie to R-shiny
I m trying to check user input if it is available in csv file or not but it is just matching 1st row of csv file not the whole csv file column.
I tried using array to check myself something like that:

```
output$usignin <- renderUI({
login <- read.csv("check.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = c("","NA"))
na.omit(login)
asd = match(login$email[3], input$email)
zxc = match(login$password[3], input$password)
if((!is.na(asd)) && (!is.na(zxc))){
  h4("Correct")
}
else{
  h4("Forgot Password?")
}
})
```

And this thing worked but i want it to be done dynamically not statically setting array values in `login$email[n]`. Tried for loop didn't worked for me any other suggestions or i might did any mistake in using for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little tough to tell with such a small sample of the code, but this should work:

```r
output$usignin <- renderUI({
login <- read.csv("check.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = c("","NA"))
na.omit(login)

asd = match(input$email, login$email)
zxc = match(input$password, login$password)

test_match <- asd == zxc

if(!is.na(test_match) && test_match){
  h4("Correct")
}
else{
  h4("Forgot Password?")
}
})
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked thank you.
But now the problem occurred is that it is validating if user email and password doesn't matches like abc@gmail.com password is 12345 and it is validating that email on 45678 so that shouldn't be done so now what should i do?

Comment: what do you mean it is validating that email on 45678?

Comment: i m saying that for example my file contains 2 records of user
`id1: abc@example.com  password: 12345`
`id2: def@example.com password: 45678`

so if now i m taking user input like
id: `abc@example.com` password: `45678`
it is making this thing correct although password for `abc@example.com` is `12345`